# Which is the better way to calculate the size of one array in a for statement?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Which is faster? are there reasons to use one over the other?
`for($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i){ ... }`
OR
`for($i = 0, $size = count($array); $i < $size; ++$i){ ... }`

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php states: "The above code can be slow, because the array size is fetched on every iteration. Since the size never changes, the loop be easily optimized by using an intermediate variable to store the size instead of repeatedly calling count():"

Is the interpreter actually that dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case in each iteration you must call the function `count()`, the time complexity is `O(n)`:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i){ ... }
```

In this case you call once `count()` at te begining, and you use the store value of `$size`, time complexity is `O(1)`. This case is more faster:

```
for($i = 0, $size = count($array); $i < $size; ++$i){ ... }
```

Comment: Yes, but does the interpreter not cache the value or even have a special clause for the very common case of looping over ever element in an array?

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski PHP arrays are mutable. It's perfectly possible for the length of the array to change between iterations.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski no, the value is calculate in each iteration

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski the second is more faster.

Comment: Obviously, the optimizer may improve over time - particularly with predictive branching - such that eventually, this will become a non-issue. However, given the choice, you are probably safer to avoid relying on the optimizer. An alternative that is a bit more readable is to do: for($i=count(array)-1; $i >= 0; --$i) {...}.  This of course, assumes that you are not depending on the ordering of the array for anything useful.